# Unable to get Application SSO Token

Tags: tomcat, single-sign-on, openam

I did following steps to implement SSO but getting token exception so that my tomcat is not getting started ,

1. I have installed Openam server on my machine on one tomcat instance which is my identity repository. My openam server is working fine. I have created the user on openam server for SSO who is going to access our application.
2. And J2EE policy agent in another tomcat to protect our application on the same machine. but when i am going to start the that  tomcat instance to acces application i am facing following exception.

   [AgentException Stack]
   com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentException: ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.getApplicationSSOToken(): Unable to get Application SSO Token
   at com.sun.identity.agents.common.ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.getApplicationSSOToken(ApplicationSSOTokenProvider.java:81)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.setAppSSOToken(AgentConfiguration.java:616)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.bootStrapClientConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:722)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.initializeConfiguration(AgentConfiguration.java:1140)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.AgentConfiguration.(AgentConfiguration.java:1579)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.arch.Manager.(Manager.java:643)
   at com.sun.identity.agents.tomcat.v6.AmTomcatRealm.(AmTomcatRealm.java:64)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

can you please suggest any solution for that. is it due to FQDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that might go wrong, some thoughts:

- Did you configure the J2EE Agent in OpenAM Server?
- Is your OpenAM server instance up-and-running when you start your agent instance?
- Are the username/password settings correct
- ...

You can find detailed explanation about configuring J2EE Policy agents on Tomcat [here](https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Installing+Tomcat+6.0+Policy+Agent).

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem using Tomcat 6.0.35 as the container of the OpenAM server (10.0.0).

In the beginning, I thought the error was in the protected Tomcat (6.0.29), which had the policy agent installed (tomcat_v6_agent_303).

Well, it turned out that **running the OpenAM Server in Jetty** 7.6.5 solved the issue.

The error pops in the policy agent, when in fact it was something on the server side that was causing it.